# How do I create a new file and write the integers to a file using an array?

Tags: java

How do I create a new file and write the integers to a file? I tried to go with online help, but I continue to receive errors.

Arrays have always been a terrible nightmare for me in class and it would be nice to have a clear understand on how to write the ints to the files.

Thanks in advance and sorry for complete ignorance on programming.

Comment: Only post the relevant code instead of posting all the imports..Read here [How to ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: 1) Why in the world do you have that many imports when you need something like 3 of them? 2) We can't read your mind. What errors are you getting? 3) Describe your problem more clearly. What outputs are you expecting, and what are you getting instead? 4) *Show* the research you have done. What did you search? What did you try? How did it not work?

Comment: Fixed, imports are gone, I'm sorry

Comment: Also, try to format your code more clearly. Currently the lines are indented a bit randomly. Fixing this very minor issue will make it easy to read (and as a result fix) your code.

Comment: Is that better indented? I'm sorry, I'm not trying to make this hard on you guys, I really want to learn!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this simple utility.

Easiest way to write ints to file

```
public class WriteInts {

    private String fname;

    public WriteInts(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    public void write(int... a) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(fname);
        try {
            System.out.println("WRiting to-" + file.getAbsolutePath());

            if (!file.exists())
                file.createNewFile();
            file.canRead();

        } catch (IOException x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedWriter outputWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            outputWriter.write(Integer.toString(a[i]));
            /*
             * Add new line to keep them seperated
             */
            outputWriter.newLine();
        }
        /*
         * Flush and close the stream
         */
        outputWriter.flush();
        outputWriter.close();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int myArr[] = { 16, 31, 90, 45, 89 };
        try {
            WriteInts wi = new WriteInts("mydata.dat");
            wi.write(myArr);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class constructor accepts a String and int as argument but you're passing a String and an array object

```
WriteInts wi = new WriteInts("mydata.dat" , myArr); // this line
```

you should change the constructor argument type to varargs if you're not sure how many ints you're gonna pass

```
public WriteInts(String ar, int a){
```

replace this line with

```
public WriteInts(String ar, int... a){
```

if you want to pass only one single int at a time, then pass the array element one by one in loop

```
WriteInts wi = new WriteInts("mydata.dat" , myArr[n]);
```

Comment: It helped some, but I still got errors once I placed the n into the myArr, I updated the code on the page to show I added it but removed the n

Comment: It just doesn't understand what the X in

Comment: write this only
WriteInts wi = new WriteInts("mydata.dat" , myArr);
don't use [ ] and then run the code

Comment: outputWriter.write(Integer.toString(x[i]));
outputWriter.newLine();
 this is now giving me a problem

Answer (score 0):

Some additional observations:

```
if (!file.exists())
file.createNewFile();
file.canRead();
```

I am not sure what you are trying to do here byt it's not necessary to create a file if it does not exist. One will be created for you via `BufferedWriter` if it does not exist. If the purpose is other, for e.g. to append to a file if it exist you can use other approaches. One such example would be:

```
BufferedWriter outputWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true)); // second argument means append
```

which uses the `FileWriter` option for appending.

If you need to create a new folder(s) to hold the new file then you **should** create it before though.

Also,   `outputWriter.flush();` is unnecessary when `outputWriter.close();` follows (it is called by `close()`).